STM32 - Is reading/writing singular bits inside registers with these custom structs ok?
Reading and writing from registers in STM32 seems to be super clunky and unintuitive to read, eg:
BRvalue = (SPI_CR1_BR & SPI1->CR1) >> SPI_CR1_BR_Pos; // Read current BR value
SPI1->CR1 &= ~SPI_CR1_BR; // Clear bits in BR position.
SPI1->CR1 |= 0b010 << SPI_CR1_BR_Pos; // Write new bits.

Coming from programming PIC's with XC8, they have these nice structs set up (inside a union because sometimes they have multiple structs where they define bit fields as singular bits too, or use different words to name bits etc.) that allow reading and writing of singular bits inside registers. I liked the balance of simplicity and readability, so wrote my own for this register for example:
typedef union {
    struct {
        volatile unsigned CPHA :1;
        volatile unsigned CPOL :1;
        volatile unsigned MSTR :1;
        volatile unsigned BR :3;
        volatile unsigned SPE :1;
        volatile unsigned LSBFIRST :1;
        volatile unsigned SSI :1;
        volatile unsigned SSM :1;
        volatile unsigned RXONLY :1;
        volatile unsigned CRCL :1;
        volatile unsigned CRCNEXT :1;
        volatile unsigned CRCEN :1;
        volatile unsigned BIDIOE :1;
        volatile unsigned BIDIMODE :1;
    };
} SPI1CR1bits_t;
SPI1CR1bits_t *SPI1CR1bits = (SPI1CR1bits_t*) &(SPI1->CR1);

Which allows the read / write operation to be done in a MUCH more elegant way:
BRvalue = SPI1CR1bits->BR; // Read value
SPI1CR1bits->BR = 0b010; // Write value

I've tested it and it seems to be working great. It also works for reading status bits that HW changes.
I haven't found this common practice though with STM32. Is there a reason why? What would be some problems I would encounter reading / writing with this method? Are there things I should be cautious of?

Probably okay. There are a few ways to define memory mapped h/w registers: yours and stm32 being some of them. To help those of us that don't want to go digging, it would help if you could edit your question and post the stm32 definitions for SPI_CR1_BR et. al. that are fully representative of the things you want to replace.

One thing: If you map your struct directly to the h/w, if you change two bits (e.g. str->SSI = 1; str->SSM = 0;), it has to fetch and store twice (e.g. tmp = reg; tmp |= SSI; reg = tmp; tmp = reg; tmp &= ~SSM; reg = tmp;). Register access can be slightly slower. So, you might want to remove the volatile from your struct and add a field: union { struct { unsigned SSI:1; unsigned SSM:1 } ; unsigned raw; }; Then, do: mystruct.raw = SPI_CR1_BR; mystruct.SSI = 1; mystruct.SSM = 0; SPI_CR1_BR = mystruct.raw; Then, you only fetch/store the h/w register once.

Some h/w expects that you fetch a temp copy of a register, modify bits in the temp variable, and write back the entire register value. That is, the h/w may expect to see multiple bits changed "atomically" in a single write to the register. Depends on the given h/w register and what the docs say.

The reason "why" is like likely that the provided header must work with multiple compilers that may not always behave identically.  Microchip provide their own compiler and their header need only work with that.  For Cortex-M3/4 at least you could read single bits atomically using bit-banding.  ST all provide higher levels of abstraction in both the Cube HAL or LL libraries, or the older (and better IMO) SPL.

Note that armcc at least will access single bit bitfields using bit-banding where possible.  Other compilers YMMV.

The layout of the bitfields is not guaranteed by the standard and is compiler dependent. Do not use bitfields for this. Create a GET_BIT and SET_BIT macro instead.

Using C bit fields will only partially work.
The main problem is that compilers implement bit fields assuming that the underlying integer variables behave like regular memory that can be read and written. So they implement write operations by first reading the underlying integer variable, modifying the relevant bits and finally writing the underlying integer variable. This assumption does not hold for all STM32 registers.
It works if all the bits in the register are of type rw, r or are unused. But it does not work it a register contains bits with a different behavior such as rc_w0, rc_w1, rc_r, t etc. In these cases, writing to the bit fields will change unintended bits in most cases.
The STM32 reference manuals document the behavior of the register bits in details and there is an explanation of the different bit behavior in the first chapter.

So the use of bit fields must be restricted to registers containing only rw, r and unused bits.
A less severe issue is that the C standard does not specify how the bit field bits are mapped to the bits of the underlying integer variable. Each compiler can implement it differently. In practice, they only differ if a struct uses more bits than fit into a single integer variable or if the bit fields in a struct use different integer data types.
This shouldn't affect STM32 registers however as they are all 32-bit integer. So just consistently use uint32_t as the integer data type and make a separate struct for each register, and you should be safe.


haven't found this common practice though with STM32. Is there a reason why?

IMO because ARM mandated a coding standard to be used by their licensees in all accompanying software (called CMSIS; unfortunately, this moniker got thrown around in promotional materials too much without proper explanation, so its message has been somewhat lost).
So, mcu manufacturers such as ST produced e.g. device headers describing the registers and their bits/bitfields according to CMSIS. And CMSIS avoids bitfields - exactly because of reasons given by @Codo in the other answer (although IMO the main reason is the vague definition of bitfields in C standard, as the problem with RMW on not-purely-memory-like registers is not bitfield specific - you will be bitten by it in the same way if using RMW through conventional |= &= operators, and even using bit-banding on Cortex-M3/M4).

As already said here, please check the read and write properties of the register bits to avoid unintended effects.
If you intend to make multiple changes altogether to a register value, as others have said in the comments, it is a good idea to work on a variable value, then commit the changes altogether.
If you add to your union an uint16_t or uint32_t field, you can read from and write to the register without casting.
Furthermore, creating your own bit structures can be error-prone; it is easy to forget a bit field or to set the wrong size while copy-pasting the structure fields.
I would recommend, if your compiler lets you, adding e.g. an assert check to verify if the structure or union size is bigger than expected.
This check anyway would not cover all the mistakes one can make while defining the structure, obviously.
// if using e.g. the STM32F76xxx series, the SPIx_CR1 registers can be accessed in 16-bit (half-words) or 32-bit (words) modes
// let'use a 16-bit structure
typedef struct {
    volatile unsigned CPHA :1;
    volatile unsigned CPOL :1;
    volatile unsigned MSTR :1;
    volatile unsigned BR :3;
    volatile unsigned SPE :1;
    volatile unsigned LSBFIRST :1;
    volatile unsigned SSI :1;
    volatile unsigned SSM :1;
    volatile unsigned RXONLY :1;
    volatile unsigned CRCL :1;
    volatile unsigned CRCNEXT :1;
    volatile unsigned CRCEN :1;
    volatile unsigned BIDIOE :1;
    volatile unsigned BIDIMODE :1;
} __attribute__((packed)) type_struct_register_SPICR1_bits;

// using C11 standard for assert
// checking if we added too many bits
_Static_assert(sizeof(type_struct_register_SPICR1_bits) != 2, "wrong size for type_struct_register_SPICR1_bits");

// union with the bits and the half-word view of the register
typedef union {
    type_struct_register_SPICR1_bits bits;
    uint16_t reg;
} type_union_16bits_register_SPICR1;
// using C11 standard for assert
// checking if the union has the expected size
_Static_assert(sizeof(type_union_register_SPICR1) != 2, "wrong size for type_union_16bits_register_SPICR1");

type_union_16bits_register_SPICR1 SPI1CR1;
// read without casting
SPI1CR1.reg = SPI1->CR1;
// if you need to make multiple assignments at once, you can do your assignments on the variable
SPI1CR1.bits.BR = 0b010;
SPI1CR1.bits.CPHA = 1;
// write without casting; commits the changes altogether
SPI1->CR1 = SPI1CR1.reg;

